# How do I set path for FileReader in Net-Beans (or Java in General)?

Tags: java, netbeans, path, filereader

I am trying to read a file using File Reader but I continue to get fileNotFound execptions which leads be to believe that clearly netbeans is not picking up on the file location. The file itself is saved in the src folder along woth the .java file.

The following code seems to fail. How can I fix this>

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/flavors.data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put your resources in src folder than you can load it like that

```
InputStream data = AnyClassInYouProject.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("flavors.data");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(data);
```

or if your resources in some package than you can load it like that

```
InputStream data = ClassInSamePackage.class.getResourceAsStream("flavors.data");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(data);
```

if your want to read it using file IO , use following method to find the default relative path in netbeans

```
//Method 1:
System.out.println( System.getProperty("user.dir"));
//Method 2:
System.out.println(new File("/").getAbsolutePath());   

//than use this to the path you want:
System.setProperty("user.dir", "/new/Path");
```

Comment: I tried the first and I got a null pointer exception, any suggestions?

Comment: It is throwing the null pointer exception at the line calling the file. The method showed me the correct path. But it does not seem to read the file.

Comment: null mean the resource could not be found,but you said the path is correct... how did you find the path ? it read as a stream. post you code plz

Comment: when I use: Method 1 I get "/Network/Servers/buffalo.cs.fiu.edu/homes/NetBeansProjects/IceCreamShop/src" which is in fact the correct path. But If I try any type of file reader I get a FileNotFoundException. When I use Input stream I get a null pointer at that exact line.

Comment: did you use `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/flavors.data");` ?

Comment: yup, and I still get a fileNotFound exception. It wont even find the .java file in the same folder.

Comment: that's so weird, make sure  `file.getAbsolutePath()`. is pointing to your file.  did you try load it from getResourceAsStream?

Comment: WOW, thank you. I was finally able to read the file. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, apparently I am a total rookie when it comes to reading files. Perhaps I misunderstood exactly what it was telling me when it was referring to the fileNotFound exceptions. All I had to do was add an exceptions throw to my method. The path was correct, it worked perfectly. Thank your for your patience.